# How to expand HTML table by looping over an array of file names?

Tags: python, html, for-loop, html-table

I'm very new to HTML. I know how to add table rows and cells and also insert images via the path. Now I have generated a bunch of image files of graphs via Python and matplotlib and sorted them into two respective directories, which I want to portray in a table. One image per cell and one directory per column basically, so that they are aligned side by side.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>graphs</title>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>"heading1</th>
        <th>heading2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <tc> image1_1</tc>
        <tc> image2_1</tc>
    </tr>
    .
    .
    .
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you saying you want to automate the process of setting up the table with the images?

Answer (score 0):

With [python](/questions/tagged/python), if you're tempted to use the [`Styler`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.html)/[`to_html`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.to_html.html) :

```py
import pandas as pd
from itertools import groupby
from pathlib import Path

(
    pd.DataFrame(
        {
            d: list(fp) for d,fp in groupby(
                Path("./").rglob("*.png"), # adjust if needed
                key=lambda p: p.parent.name
            )
        }
    ).map('<img src="{}" width="70%" height="70%">'.format)
        .style.hide(axis=0).set_caption("Graphs")
        .set_table_styles(
            [
                dict(selector="*", props=[
                    ("text-align", "center"),
                    ("width", "500px")
                ]),
                dict(selector="caption", props=[
                    ("padding-left", "200px"),
                    ("font-weight", "bold"),
                    ("font-size", "20px")
                ])
            ],
        )
    .to_html("table.html")
)
```

Output (*table.html*) :

[image]

Used input :

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(0)
data = np.random.randn(100)

def mkplot(data, filename, color, plot_type):
    plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5))    
    if plot_type == "LP":
        plt.plot(data, color)
    elif plot_type == "SP":
        plt.scatter(range(100), data, color=color)
    elif plot_type == "HI":
        plt.hist(data, bins=20, color=color)
    elif plot_type == "BP":
        plt.bar(range(10), data[:10], color=color)
    
    plt.savefig(filename, dpi=300)

mkplot(data, "dir1/1.png", "lightcoral", "LP")
mkplot(data, "dir1/2.png", "blue", "SP")
mkplot(data, "dir2/3.png", "lightgreen", "HI")
mkplot(data, "dir2/4.png", "black", "BP")
```